# How to check if a variable has been assigned or not?

Tags: dolphindb

I have a variable “result” with initial value of NULL, which will be assigned with a table when a certain condition is met. And I want to check if the variable is NULL or a table in the follow-up script. If I use the function `isNULL` or write `==NULL`, it checks whether each element of the table is null or not. How can I correct the script to return a Boolean scalar for the object?

```
result = NULL
if(cond) { result = func() }
if(result == NULL) {    // error is raised if result is a table
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check NULL value with `type(result) == 0`. In DolphinDB, data type ID 0 means the VOID type.

Alternatively, you can use function `isVoid` which checks if the object is of VOID type. Suppose t1 has not been assigned:

```
isVoid(1 NULL 2);
0

// compare with function isNull
isNull(1 NULL 2);
[0,1,0]
```